# How to create different versions of a site in Liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

I have built my site with default language being in Spanish and now I want to build the English version of it. I have added the link 'In English' to the Spanish site, and when clicked takes me to www.example.com/en. The control panel on the English site converts to English as well, which is fine. Then I try to translate the contents from Spanish to English.

Here is what I do: let's say I take the 'Contact' menu, where I have the contact page. In the URL then it looks like this: www.example.com/en/contact. Through Edit, I go to the text editor, localize the language to English, change the title and the content of the page into English and save it in a hope to see the changes on the English version only, but the change is also shown on the Spanish version, that is it overrides the Spanish version, which means that the page is the same on both the language versions. I thought the copy that is under www.example.com/en/contact is a different instance of the web content than that on www.example.com/contact, but I was wrong.

The question is how to create the English version of the site then? Should I copy the whole site's theme into a folder e.g. /en and make the changes from there? or there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Create a content

[image: create a content]

2: Add tranlation

[image: add tranlation]

3: Put tranlation

[image: put tranlation]

with www.example.com/en/contact, www.example.com/bg/contact, etc. you can see the tranlation.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help and your demo. I got it working now.